Providing lifetime of the struct itself to trait's lifetime argument?
I have the following Rust code.
trait X<'a> {
    fn x(&self) -> &'a [f64];
}

struct Owned{
    x: Vec<f64>,
}

struct Ref<'a> {
    x: &'a[f64],
}

I'd like to implement X for both Ref and Owned.
For Ref, this is easy.
impl<'a> X<'a> for Ref<'a> {
    fn x(&self) -> &'a [f64] { self.x }
}

For Owned, I'd like fn x(&self) to return &self.x, but I don't know how to say that Owned implements X<'lifetime-of-the-struct-itself>.  How can I do that?

Why do you need the returned slice to have the lifetime of the trait parameter and not of the reference &self ?

In the actual code, Ref holds a reference to raw data and a field describing "how to interpret the data". So, I sometimes need to reinterpret the data in different ways, and an intermediate object can get discarded before the final object.

Imagine I want to make a linear algebra library, and I have an "OwnedMatrix" struct and an "MatrixView" struct (providing transposed view, vectorized view, etc.). When you do such operations twice, the first view can get discarded before using the second view (That can be made valid by composing the view operations first.)

Instead of adding to the trait a lifetime parameter, add a Generic Associated Type that you use for the method's return type:
use std::ops::Deref;

trait X {
    type Out<'out>: Deref<Target = [f64]> where Self: 'out;
    fn x(&self) -> Self::Out<'_>;
}

struct Owned {
    x: Vec<f64>,
}

struct Ref<'a> {
    x: &'a [f64],
}

impl<'a> X for Ref<'a> {
    type Out<'out> = &'a [f64] where 'a: 'out;
    fn x(&self) -> &'a [f64] { self.x }
}

impl X for Owned {
    type Out<'out> = &'out [f64];
    fn x(&self) -> &[f64] { &self.x }
}

See it on the playground.

This doesn't explain why the original approach doesn't work (or how to fix it), which might be useful for situations when one can't modify the trait definition.

I also want to add a default implementation of a function in trait X returning &self.x()[some slice], but this solution would give me "insufficient lifetime" error. That would not happen if I wrote it in the definition of Ref and Owned directly.
